# .htaccess is not working under xampp and Ubuntu

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I am trying to do a url rewrite with .htaccess that is not working. I have xampp installed on a Ubuntu Linux machine. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    #From: host/1/products/productname/30/
    #To: host/1/index.php?product=productname&price=30
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^1/products/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ 1/index.php?product=$1&price=$2
```

The comment lines in the code show what I am trying to do. I know that .htaccess is being read because if I uncomment the "From" line above, it throws a 500 server error. Otherwise, I get a 404 Object not found error. I have set AllowOverride All in httpd.conf and restarted apache. The error_log is not reporting an error.

Any ideas?

This is my .htaccess as of Dec 2 at 2:05 PM

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

#From: host/1/products/productname/30/
#To: host/1/index.php?product=productname&price=30
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^1/products/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ 1/index.php?product=$1&price=$2
RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar`
```

Comment: What happens when you visit `/1/index.php?product=productname&price=30` in your browser?

Comment: When I visit http://localhost/1/index.php?product=productname&price=30, the page is properly styled

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Is there any other .htaccess in the system?

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented and AllowOverride is set to All

Comment: Create a simple rule: `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R]` and open `/foo` in your browser. See if it redirects to `/bar` or not.

Comment: I added the rule you suggested and created /bar. When I go to /foo, I get an error 404. When I go to /bar, I get the directory listing. Apparently .htaccess is not working. However, it is being read because I can uncomment the #From or #To line and get a error 500. I am really stumped here.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` in `/1/` directory as well?

Comment: I found two .htaccess files inside of /hrdocs. None seem to be relevant to this issue:`./.htaccess
./xampp/sqlite/.htaccess`

Comment: Ok, can you post your complete code from `./.htaccess`?

Comment: Sorry, that should have said I found two .htaccess files inside of /htdocs. The first is the file I am working with and the second is not an issue ./.htaccess ./xampp/sqlite/.htaccess

Comment: Right `./xampp/sqlite/.htaccess` doesn't matter here. If you can post code from `./.htaccess` that should tell us something.

Comment: I got an error while trying to post .htaccess in a comment so I edited my original post and appended it with the current .htaccess

Comment: ok comment out foo/bar rule and try this rule: **`RewriteRule ^1/products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /1/index.php?product=$1&price=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`**

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: Man, what a pain!!! I added the rule you suggested and still, going to http://localhost/1/products/productname/30/ brings up index.php without styling

Comment: Oh for styles and images etc make sure to use absolute paths. Let me post an answer with all this.

Comment: Getting very late here. Provided you an answer. Check it out, it should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^1/products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /1/index.php?product=$1&price=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**For css/js/images:** Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Alternatively** You can try adding this in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

to resolve all the relative resource links.